# Why are two of my plants drying out and turning yellow?

Tags: houseplants, dryness

I have 2 plants that are drying out.

One is called [aglaonema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aglaonema) and the other one is a [ravenea palm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravenea). I water them every week and don't know why they're turning yellow.

Comment: Are you overwatering perhaps? http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9265/why-are-my-aglaonemas-leaves-turning-yellow-rapidly

Comment: I put water every week.The palm plant is call ravenea and is turning yellow.

Comment: It would be great if you can share some pictures as well as details about where they are located and your geographic location as well

Comment: There are located in the living room next to the wall.I don't know how to add pictures

Comment: Great time to learn Rosa!  It is not tough and we'll be able to guide you.  We HAVE to have pictures.  Otherwise it is irresponsible to answer!