# Why are the leaves on my pink Aglaonema fading and turning yellow?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, leaves

My Aglaonema is fading rapidly. The leaves are pale in appearance and are turning yellow. Can you tell me what is happening?

Comment: assuming it's indoors, how long have you had it? Does it receive direct sunlight? And a photo would be very helpful

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9265/why-are-my-aglaonemas-leaves-turning-yellow-rapidly

Answer (score 1):

Truly have to have a picture so my answer is that of a blind person, okay?  These plants do so well in shade otherwise I'd say it needed more light.  So it is more likely a chemical deficiency.  Have you fertilized this plant?  Is it in potting soil?  One of the chemicals (I hate the word nutrients, nutrition or food because these chemicals are NOT food...plants make their own food) would be manganese.  We need to know if you, again, have ever fertilized, if so when was the last time, what was the formulation of this fertilizer?  These are all questions we will ask even after we see your picture.

The fix is to spray Manganese Chelate right on the leaves but do not do that willy nilly.  You have to know for sure that this is the problem.  If you've never fertilized I would go get OSMOCOTE 15-5-10 as this is meant for foliage.  Otherwise OSMOCOTE 14-14-14 is more all around and can be used for foliage plants as well as flowering/vegetables.  I am NOT a Scott's company fan at all and this is the ONLY product I would purchase from them.  Tried and true and simple and lasts a long time.  I wouldn't use it more than twice per year, same amount that is in the directions but only twice per year not 4 times per year.  Doesn't have manganese that I could find, so I would look for that separately.  Try Osmocote and wait a week or two and if your plant hasn't colored up then go get the manganese spray.  Go to a cannabis store, they've got the best products, more fine tuned products, professional versus mass produced, and their staff usually KNOW what they are talking about concerning plants, not just cannabis!

Do read the label and material closely to see if there are any added micro chemicals...I know the label says FOOD for plants and FEEDING but they are trying to sell product to those who don't understand.  More is NOT better!!

Send a picture we might have to change answers, add to the answers so this is just a place to start as a blind person...thanks[care of aglonema http://alphabotanical.com/aglaonema.php#content_3](http://alphabotanical.com/aglaonema.php#content_3)

Go to the second page for the blurb on manganese but don't get into 'misting', doesn't work.  I do however put my house plants in the shower every 3 months or so to water and wash off all the dust. Cold water okay?  Misting has been clearly shown to NOT improve the humidity at all and could cause problems with too much water and thus fungus.